# Google Maps API v3 - how to get infoBox outside Map div

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In Google Map API v3 I'd like to show infoBox (or infoWindow) as a div, that has let's say 30% width, map's max height, and it's positioned absolutely on the left side of the map. I've seen implementation of this, where actual infoBox was outside Map div (example: http://www.londontypographica.com/map/).

The main problem is that inline styles of infoBox position the box according to marker's cordinates (or specified in options), plus it seems that theyare positioned absolutely relatively to map container. I don't know how to remove those inline styles. Here's example of those styles (they are calculated every time i click on marker so i most likely need to disable that function or something):

```
<div class="infoBox" style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; width: 43px; left: 500.44037546636537px; top: 234.43615104886703px; cursor: default;">(...)<div>
```

In short: I want to remove inline styles (or prevent applying it when marker is clicked) of infoBox, and move it outside of google map container (so i can easly position and size the element). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use info box.  You can just handle the marker click event and populate any div you want with whatever data you want.

That's what's going on in the example you linked to.  On the marker click event, it's centering the map on the marker, and loading a div with the corresponding image.

Comment: Thanks, that's totally doable, altho is it the "best practice" for solving this kind of problem? Btw don't wanna make new topic, but is there a chance you know how i can change center point like in the example i've provided (marker moves to right when u pop info window).

Comment: ^Nvm about centering, found out panBy method works fine to do that.

Comment: @Malyo, there's no best practice here. It's whatever works for your site. The only thing I would suggest is to make sure the "external info box" is adjacent to the map canvas, not somewhere across the other side of the screen. And maybe visually link the two with some sort of border round both areas. Alternatively, if you want a popup div, then try to make sure it doesn't obscure the map.